# complie ffmpeg erro when dxva2

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, compiler-errors, dxva

config ffmpeg:

```
./confingure --toolchain=msvc
```

the error occured:

```
make: *** [libavcodec/dxva2.o] Error 1
```

my system is win10 and ffmpeg is latest.

Comment: Your question is very incomplete, we need more info. Are you using MSVC for a C++ project? I see bash-style execution and you mention win10, is that cygwin? In that case, why not use gcc? Andlast but not least, there is a typo in your command.

Comment: oh,sorry. I was used MSVC to complie ffmpeg.use msys2 with mingw32. e,does my command error? I look at the configure help,dxva2 will be configured default.